Kernel of parabolic equation for bounded function.
Let $\varphi$ be a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$. Consider the following parabolic equation: for $d>0$
\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u_t = du_{xx} + \varphi(x,t)& x\in \mathbb{R},\textbf{ }t>0\\
u(x,0) = 0
\end{array}\right..
\end{align*}
Based on the book of Lorenzi and Rhandi [1], chapter 5, we know that
\begin{align*}
u(x,t) = \int_0^t \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi d (t-s)}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\dfrac{-|x-y|^2}{4d(t-s)}}\varphi(y,s)dyds.
\end{align*}
In the book, the authors prove that function $u$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times [0, T]$. My question:
Is it possible to prove the continuity of $u$ if $\varphi$ is only a measurable, bounded function? If so, please give some of your advice. If not, please give a counter-example.
Thank you in advance,
Best regards,

[1] https://www.routledge.com/Semigroups-of-Bounded-Operators-and-Second-Order-Elliptic-and-Parabolic-Partial-Differential-Equations/Lorenzi-Rhandi/p/book/9780367206291

I believe that the function $\phi$ must be continuous. Given that $\phi$ is measurable and bounded, we know that $u \in L^2(0, T; H^2(\mathbb{R}))$. Due to the properties of the heat kernel we can extend this such that $u \in L^2(0, T; H^2(\mathbb{R})) \cap H^1(0, T; L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, thereby both spatial derivatives and time derivative are square-integrable. Since
$$
\phi(x,t) = u_t - u_{xx}
$$
we know that $\phi \in L^2$, based on the fact that both $u_t, u_{xx} \in L^2$. By Sobolev embedding theorem we also know that we can embed $H_2(\mathbb{R}) \subset C(\mathbb{R}) $ and  $H_1(\mathbb{R}) \subset C(\mathbb{R}) $. Now we use the fact that $u \in L^2(0, T; H^2(\mathbb{R})) \cap H^1(0, T; L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ to prove that $u$ continuous. Therefore,
$\phi$ needn't be continuous.
Edit 1: Perhaps I should also include the reason as to why we can assume that the time derivative implies that $u$ in $H^1$ this comes from the fact that $u_{xx} \in L^2$ and $\phi \in L^2$ since it is measurable and bounded. Therefore $u_t$ is at least in a weak sense differentiable.

You give a good perspective to prove this problem. Thank you so much. I think from $u\in L^2(0.T;H^2(\mathbb{R}))$, we can only obtain $u_x$ is continuous and $u_{xx}$ may not be continuous. So, $\varphi$ needs not to be continuous.

Oh yeah you are right, I am not sure what I was thinking when writing that part :). We know that for the sufficient regularity of the solution since $u$ , the derivatives must only be continuous in the weak sense so yeah in fact $\phi$ needn't be continuous
